# How to create an in-app product that can be purchased N number of time?

Tags: android, play-billing-library

**How can we create a product that can be purchased unlimited times?**. I tried consuming of purchase which makes the product available for purchase again, but **what if consume fails**?? How to handle this case?.

Thanks and Appreciate your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, retry the consume call.

You should do queryPurchases when you app launched and consume all unconsumed consumeable items.